# How to refer multiple equations

Tags: cross-referencing

I have four different equations numbered as Eqs. (1), (2), (3), (4).

I want to refer them like Eqs. (1-4) in a text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a\label{a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b\label{b}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c\label{c}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d\label{d}
\end{equation}

\Cref{a,c} are equations, as are \cref{b,d}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I did all you said, but now question marks appear instead of all equation numbers in sentences.

Comment: compile one more time.

Comment: (either that or you have an undefined reference)